# Device that emits pleasant odor automatically

Tags: single-word-requests

In a hospital I once saw an electrically-powered device, which had a little tank filled with some fluid. That tank seemed to be heated, and the vapors of the fluid filled the room with an agreeable smell. It ran all the time and improved the smell of the air inside the room continously (i. e. it wasn't an aerosol, which you spray manually).

Example sentence (X is the word I'm looking for):

> There was X on the table next to the bed and filled the room with a smell of rose petals.

What do you call such a device?

Comment: I'd call it an air freshener. That doesn't imply automatic, necessarily, but if it's "on the table" I'd assume it was what you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was it an **aroma diffuser** ?

[image]

Essentially seems to be a fancier  version  of the simpler **plug-in air freshener** as in picture below. Both are made up of two main components:

- electrical diffuser
- plug-in air freshener refills.

[image]

Comment: It was a bit bigger and it stood on the nightstand.

Comment: @DP_  Connected to the mains or battery based ?

Comment: Connected to the mains.

Comment: @DP_You can get battery-powered ones. I helped someone sell their parents' home, and as both the occupants had been in their nineties, and suffered dementia, the place had an inevitable "geriatric" odour. After clearing the place we put one of these things in every room, before inviting potential buyers to view.

Answer (score 0):

In the days before regular bathing, many folks carried a small device that was charged with perfume to make the atmosphere more pleasing they also had low tech devices for use in room. Both of which came under the category of POMANDER:

> a ball or perforated container of sweet-smelling substances such as herbs and spices, placed in a closet, drawer, or room to perfume the air or (formerly) carried as a supposed protection against infection.
>
> — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomander